# Natural hot shower

Tags: geology, water

Was there a geological era in which the rain on earth was harmless and with the same temperature of the water in a hot shower?

Comment: It happens here in Abu Dhabi the rare times it rains, so I assume it can happen elsewhere in a warm climate.  In any case, the geological era is now.  Did you mean worldwide?  Also: welcome to Worldbuilding!

Comment: @Mikey: leave the marketing to the professional; "in Abu Dhabi you can enjoy 90mins of diamond infused outdoor hot shower and a relaxing 24-carat gold facial treatment..."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It would appear that it can happen - https://www.wunderground.com/blog/JeffMasters/hottest-rain-on-record-rain-falls-at-115f-in-needles-california

Whether it was ever commonplace or not though I don't know.